# Finding gradient of line using graph equation and given point

Tags: calculus

Consider a parabola *y* = *x*$^2$. The line that goes through the point (0, $\frac{3}{2}$) and is orthogonal to a tangent line to the part of the parabola with *x* > 0 is *y* = A*x* + $\frac{3}{2}$. Find the value of A

The answer is supposedly $\frac{-1}{2}$ but I'm not sure how they got to that answer.

Comment: Do you know the general equation for normal through parabola? It passes through $(0, 3/2) $.

Comment: I know how to derive the normal equation from the gradient for the tangent but I do not know the general equation

Comment: -@A Brudvik-Linder, [See this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.toppr.com/content/concept/normal-to-a-parabola-207438/&ved=2ahUKEwjSqtjZtfvqAhXXT30KHb19Ae0QFjAVegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw06jUunevmdhWnI3h-Ezx7h). Difference is that you have to swap $x$ to $y$ as this formula is for $y^2=x$ and yours is $y=x^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $(x_0,x_0^2)$ is the point on the parabola $y=x^2$ where the tangent line and its perpendicular line through $(0,\frac{3}{2})$ intersect. Note that $y'=2x$, which means the slope of the tangent line at $(x_0,x_0^2)$ is $2x_0$, hence the slope of its perpendicular line is $-\frac{1}{2x_0}$. Thus, we have $A = -\frac{1}{2x_0}$. Because the perpendicular line passes through $(0,\frac{3}{2})$, we have
\begin{align*}
y = Ax+\frac{3}{2} \implies x_0^2 &= -\frac{1}{2x_0}x_0+\frac{3}{2},\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2},\\
&= 1.
\end{align*}
Given that $x>0$, we find $x_0 = 1$, which means $(x_0,x_0^2) = (1,1)$. And so, we find that $\boxed{A = -\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: Try to give hints first rather than providing complete solution. Also, ask OP for their attempt or what more they know about the context. [Read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution).

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this in mind.